# How to add iOS target project to a Xamarin forms Prism project which has only Android configure it?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, prism

I have a Xamarin Forms Prism project with only Android in the solution now I want to add iOS to the solution. is there any way to accomplish this with a template or do I have to manually configure it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that automatically. Now whether you will add a new project and install nugets and set references there, of you will create a new solution and import current projects there, it is up to you to decide.